# keep polling Socket.io connection infinitely

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

Socketio making infinite socket request from react to express server connection.
My server is HTTPS server and React is also running on `HTTPS=true`. When i am creating a socket on different `port` (eg, 7001) without passing `httpsServer` the client is establishing websocket connection perfectly. By the moment I pass the server directly to the `socketio(httpServer, {...options})` react is not switching to websocket connection from polling.

Client side code
**SocketApp.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const sock = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    sock.current = io("/");   
}, []);
```

**.env**

```
HTTPS=true
```

**setupProxy.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = (app) => {
  const socketProxy = createProxyMiddleware("/socket.io", {
    target: "https://localhost:5000",
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
  });
  app.use(socketProxy);
};
```

Server side code

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const { createServer } = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const httpsServer = createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'cert.pem')),
  },
      app,
    );
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'https://localhost:3005',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
  }),
);

const iosocket = socketio(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'https://localhost:3005',
    credentials: true,
  },
});

iosocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('start', (data) => {
    console.log('data :', data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
});

httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server started at', PORT);
});
```

What type of problem is this. Can't we connect https server socket?

Comment: Do you have any error message in the console ?

Comment: no the console has no error, just the polling is called again and again and also the `connection: close` is showing in the **response** but in the other ports its showing `connection: keep-alive`  @UndefinedUserAtSO

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something... You create a server http**s**Server but socket create httpServer

Comment: no, the server is httpsServer, if i mention any particular port then the socket connect as http/ws, which dont call infinitely but if i pass the httpsServer the socket is https/wss which is calling socket infinitely. [ https://imgur.com/a/Wcs7sVz ] (SCREENSHOT) @SwaD